# Which database should I choose?

Tags: mysql, nosql, redis, real-time, high-availability

I have a 37 x 150000 records in MySQL which is mainly a key-value sort of data it could represented as:

```
+---------------+---------+
| Key           | Value   |
+---------------+---------+
| 22.789:77.456 | value 1 |
| 22.786:77.678 | value 2 |
|               |         |
```

I want a fast retrieval of data, so migrated it to Redis but issue is I have only 1.6 GB of RAM and the size of data to be stored is 4 GB, hence redis will not work in this case because it need all in memeory storage.

Is there any better option than MySQL which can work with only 1.6 GB of RAM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite works like a charm with Python. It's small, portable, single-flat-file and can surprise you with what it can do. I'm working with it with a small DB of about 200k records, 30MB and is quite fast once you set the indexes and disable transactions.

Comment: I do not have 30MB, i have 4GB of data; are you sure that it will still work faster than MySQL or may be some nosql options.

Comment: Yes dude...If you will perform text based query then mysql is ok.But here you are just fetching two columns. So no need to use Mysql.
SQLite is good to use with Python. Python is a lightweight script. So its good to use SQLite with Python, As per my perspective.. Actually I have tried SQLite thats why I'm telling You.